# should i use custom campaigns (utm) for links to other sites?

Tags: google-analytics

I post quite a few news links that go to outside sources/websites and i'm just not sure if there's any point to adding custom campaign parameters (google analytics; utm) to those links. is there any kind of tracking that can be done on links that don't send people to my site?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should not, unless you have some sort of affiliate deal with the other site and they ask to to add parameters to identify traffic you send to them.

But parameters in outgoing links will show up in the GA account of the linked site, not in your own, so this will be of no use to you.

Comment: that's what i was thinking. i haven't found anything contrary. the only use i can think of is that the other site might take note of the traffic from my site. or..., that's discoverable in referral traffic. i guess there's no use. tnx.